# Import Error on deploying a flask app on apache

Tags: apache-2.4, python, mod-wsgi, flask

I am trying to deploy a flask app on a VPS using WSGI. I am not using a virtualenv, and pandas is installed on the system:

```
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
>>> print 'Works!'
Works!
```

Still I get this error:

```
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876184 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860] mod_wsgi (pid=24086): Target WSGI script '/var/www/im/server.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876217 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860] mod_wsgi (pid=24086): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/im/server.wsgi'.
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876236 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876254 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860]   File "/var/www/im/server.wsgi", line 7, in <module>
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876278 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860]     from UI import app as application
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876286 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860]   File "/var/www/im/UI/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876297 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860]     import pandas as pd
[Sat Jun 01 16:02:52.876315 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 24086] [client 27.7.8.82:59860] ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Here is the WSGI file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/im/")

from UI import app as application
application.secret_key = 'Add your secret key'
```

can someone point out what is wrong? I am trying this on a Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have one more Python interpreter installed on the box.
To check that do the following:

- From server console run python and execute these command:

  ```
  import sys
  print sys.path
  ```
- Create a test Flask app **run.py** below, place it into `/var/www/im/` folder and edit WSGI file to load it: `from run import app as application`

  ```
  import sys
  from flask import Flask
  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/')
  def get_path():
      return str(sys.path)
  ```
- compare output from both

Comment: Good advice, I've actually managed to solve my own problem following those steps, Python 3.5 was used by Apache while my CLI resolved python 2.7